# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused

Tags: php, html, mysqli, xampp, localhost

I am new in php and doing a login/register page in localhost using xampp on mac. I am having a trouble with this error:

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in /opt/lampp/htdocs/website/includes/dbh.inc.php on line 9
>   Connection failed: Connection refused

I have tried changing the code but it continuously adding more problems.

This is my code:

```
<?php

$servername = "192.168.64.2:8080";
$dBUsername = "root";
$dBPassword = "";
$dBName = "loginsystem";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

How can I eliminate this error?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to connect to other port than the default one, add the port argument when you establish the connection, not define it within the server name.

```
$servername = "192.168.64.2";
$dBUsername = "root";
$dBPassword = "";
$dBName = "loginsystem";
$dbPort = "8080";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dBUsername, $dBPassword, $dBName, $dbPort);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Another thing is to make sure you have the right port of MySQL service, port `8080` is commonly picked as the alternative for port `80` to handle HTTP request. Check your XAMPP configuration to find out which port is used for MySQL.

Comment: Still having the error. But thanks for the reply